# Leaving keel shanthi post

Tags: rituals, temple, agamas, curse, priests

There are many posts in temple - melshanthi, keelshanthi, brahmavahaka, tantri etc. It is said temple wud have given them umbuli land sealing a karanmai relationship that is serving the God till there is a last male heir. If this is broken, people fear wrath of the deity is invoked. If the next heir is studious and wants to go into a different branch, then what?